# Enterprise Architect add associated class as attribute automatically

Tags: associations, enterprise-architect

As title says it all, is it possible to set Enterprise Architect to automatically add associated class as attribute? Of course when direction of the releationship is correctly set. It would save me so much pain when creating large net of domain models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve that is to react in an add-in on the `EA_OnPostNewConnector` event. There you can inspect the role and add an appropriate attribute.

However, if you first create the attribute and then define the role in the connector you can choose the right role name from the drop down.

**Edit** According to the comment you can use `EA_OnPreDeleteConnector` to clean attributes on deletion of a connector.

Comment: For completeness, you'd probably want to delete the attributes automatically too. There is an EA_OnPreDeleteConnector event, but it should be noted that that is triggered before the connector is deleted, not after -- there are no PostDelete events (as opposed to creation events, which do come in both pre and post flavor).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct as far as getting EA to do it on the fly.

As an alternative, you could write a script (probably a "diagram" script) which creates (and deletes, see my comment on Thomas' answer) the attributes as required, and then invoke that when you're done with the connectors.

A script can make the same changes to a model an Add-In can (same API), but it can't react to events.

Comment: Absolutely. Often I prefer the use of such semi-automatic scripts over the fully automated add-ins.